# Bipartite graphs

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I want to draw something similar to this in latex. How can I do it? I want it to be a directed graph and want to be able to label the vertices.

[image: Bipartite graph]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One option would be to use [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); the package is very well documented, and you'll find many examples in the documentation. Another source of examples can be found at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/)

Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt,text width=2cm},
  ->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
]

% the vertices of U
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) [label=left: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of V
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach \i in {6,7,...,9}
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) [label=right: \i] {};
\end{scope}

% the set U
\node [myblue,fit=(f1) (f5),label=above:$U$] {};
% the set V
\node [mygreen,fit=(s6) (s9),label=above:$V$] {};

% the edges
\draw (f1) -- (s6);
\draw (s6) -- (f2);
\draw (f2) -- (s7);
\draw (s7) -- (f3);
\draw (s8) -- (f3);
\draw (f3) -- (s9);
\draw (s9) -- (f5);
\draw (f5) -- (s6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I add a variation of the previous graph (requested in a comment); each vertex will now be a labelled ordered pair. The idea is to use multiple variables in each `\foreach` construct; the first variable will be used to add a name to each node and to create the labels; the second and third variables will give the first and second coordinates of each ordered pair. The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  fsnode/.style={},
  ssnode/.style={},
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=5pt,text width=2cm},
  ->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
]

% the vertices of U
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach \i/\xcoord/\ycoord in {1/6/8,2/5/1,3/-4/7,4/6/9,5/0/-3}
  \node[fsnode,on chain,label=left:$t_{\i}$] (f\i) {$(\xcoord,\ycoord)$};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of V
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach \i/\xcoord/\ycoord in {6/0/3,7/1/4,8/-2/1,9/5/9}
  \node[ssnode,on chain,label=right:$t_{\i}$] (s\i) {$(\xcoord,\ycoord)$};
\end{scope}

% the set U
\node [myblue,fit=(f1) (f5),label=above:$U$] {};
% the set V
\node [mygreen,fit=(s6) (s9),label=above:$V$] {};

% the edges
\draw (f1) -- (s6);
\draw (s6) -- (f2);
\draw (f2) -- (s7);
\draw (s7) -- (f3);
\draw (s8) -- (f3);
\draw (f3) -- (s9);
\draw (s9) -- (f5);
\draw (f5) -- (s6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. I've one small request. Instead of colored dots if I need a value like `$(5,6)$`,`$(1,2)$` etc. what should I do ? If possible could you please add an answer without editing the first one. It will be helpful for future reference. Thank you

Comment: @Sunil: let me see if I understand: the numbers (1,2,...,8) should not appear; each vertex will be an ordered pair and you don't want the colored dots, but just the ordered pair?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Exactly but instead of the numbers I can use any labeling like (t1,t2,...,t9).

Comment: @Sunil: just to be sure, is it something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/3P45J.png) what you want?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Precisely.

Comment: @Sunil: I added the new code.

Comment: How can we add weight to the edges please

Comment: Awesome stuff! How would you make the arrows undirected?

Answer (score 11):

I come here after the battle but I hope to give some interesting informations.

1. There is a new librairie `graphs` in the cvs version but I think there is a bug in the documentation you need to replace : `\usetikzlibrary{graph}` by  `\usetikzlibrary{ graphs, graphs.standard}` without `graphs.standard`I get an error : `$`missing

   An example like your code (I don't get color blue and color green for the two sets)

   ```
   \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \usetikzlibrary{
     graphs,
     graphs.standard
   }

   \begin{document}
   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
   \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph[nodes={draw, circle,fill=myblue}, radius=.5cm,
              empty nodes, branch down=1 cm,
              grow right sep=4cm] {subgraph I_nm [V={a, b, c, d, e}, W={1,...,4}];
     a -- { 1};
     b -- { 1, 2 };
     c -- { 2,3, 4 };
     e -- { 1,4}
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The result:

   [image: with graph from tikz]
2. I made a package `tkz-berge` an I think it will be on the ctan servers the next week. I need to finish some tools for the documentation

   ```
   \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{tkz-berge}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes}

   \begin{document}

   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
   \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt,text width=2cm, line width=1pt}]
   \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
         \SetUpVertex[Math,Lpos=-180,LabelOut]
        \SetVertexNormal[FillColor=myblue,OuterSep=0pt,TextColor=myblue]
        \grEmptyPath[form=2,x=0,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=U]{5}
        \SetVertexShade[BallColor=mygreen,OuterSep=0pt]
        \SetUpVertex[Lpos=0]
        \SetVertexNormal[FillColor=mygreen,TextColor=mygreen]
        \grEmptyPath[form=2,x=6,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=V]{4}
        \SetUpEdge[lw=2pt,color=black]
       \Edges(U4,V3,U3,V2,U1)
       \Edges(U3,V3,U0,V0,U2,V1)
    % the set U
   \node [myblue,fit=(U0) (U4),label=above:\textcolor{myblue}{$U$}] {};
   % the set V
   \node [mygreen,fit=(V0) (V3),label=above:\textcolor{mygreen}{$V$}] {};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The result is fine but it would be better to draw ellipses in the background before drawing edges

   [image]

Comment: @Sunil : If you want to look at some graphs, the page about tkz-berge is here `http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/berge/index.html`

Comment: In fact, my first idea was to provide a solution using your `tkz-graph` package (which I like so much and I've used before), but since I read elsewhere (at least I undestood so) that it is not available right now, I refrained from doing so and opted for a basic `tikz` solution.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina The new versions of tkz-graph and tkz-berge are ready  for pgf 2.0 and work with pgf 2.1 but I need to correct the documentations. The next versions will be optimize  to pgf 2.1 and adapt to pgfkeys. I upload all my work the next week.

Comment: @Altermundus: I'm sorry. I'm not that familiar with drawing in latex and also that was a main reason for me to post a question without a try. All I did was copy @Gonzalo's answer and it worked perfectly. I tried both of your answer but I keep getting error. It's not finding some package I guess.

Comment: @Sunil My english is not very good so perhaps I'm not clear. The first solution needs to work with `pgf 2.1 version CVS`, you need to download the cvs version to compile this solution. The second solution works only with my package but you need to download the package from my site or to wait 10 or 15 days if you want find it on the ctan servers.

Comment: @Altermundus: I'm looking forward to seeing your packages. Thanks for writing them.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a mockup using [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}

  % Define nodes/vertices
  \multido{\i=5+-1}{5}{\pnode(1,\i){U\i}}% Vertices in U
  \multido{\i=4+-1}{4}{\pnode[0,0.5](4,\i){V\i}}% Vertices in V

  % Draw vertex set/ellipses
  \psset{linestyle=solid,linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,fillstyle=none}%
  \psellipse[linecolor=blue!80!white](1,3)(1.25,3)% U
  \psellipse[linecolor=green!40!black](4,3)(1.25,2.5)% V
  % Vertex set/ellipse labels
  \rput[u](1,6.5){$U$}% U
  \rput[u](4,6){$V$}% V

  % Node/vertex connections/edges
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=0.5pt}%
  \psline(U5)(V4)
  \psline(U4)(V4) \psline(U4)(V3)%
  \psline(U3)(V2) \psline(U3)(V1)%
  \psline(U2)(V3)%
  \psline(U1)(V4) \psline(U1)(V1)%
  
  % Draw nodes/vertices and labels
  \psset{fillstyle=solid}%
  \multido{\i=5+-1}{5}{% U vertex set
    \pscircle[fillcolor=blue!80!white](U\i){0.2}% Print vertex
    \uput{10pt}[l](U\i){$U_\i$}% Print vertex label
  }%
  \multido{\i=4+-1}{4}{% V vertex set
    \pscircle[fillcolor=green!40!black](V\i){0.2}% Print vertex
    \uput{10pt}[r](V\i){$V_\i$}% Print vertex label
  }%
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bipartite graph using pstricks]

Comment: Seems much simple ( at least to understand ). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just if anyone is interested, I modify some of the answers to make a tripartite graph

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
      every node/.style={draw,circle},
      fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
      ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
      rsnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
      %every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt,text width=2cm},
      %->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
      style1/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-1pt,text width=1.5cm},
      style2/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt,text width=4cm,text heigth=16cm,ellipse ratio=2},
      ->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
    ]

    % the vertices of U
    \begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=7mm,yshift=1.5cm]
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,3}
      \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) [label=left: \i] {};
    \end{scope}

    % the vertices of V
    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=1.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
    \foreach \i in {6,7,...,8}
      \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) [label=right: \i] {};
    \end{scope}

    % the vertices of W
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=2.5cm,start chain=going right,node distance=7mm]
    \foreach \i in {6,7,...,8}
      \node[ssnode,on chain] (t\i) [label=right: \i] {};
    \end{scope}


    % the set U
    \node [myblue,fit=(f1) (f3),label=above:$U$,style1] {};
    % the set V
    \node [mygreen,fit=(s6) (s8),label=above:$V$,style1] {};
    % the set W
    \node [mygreen,fit=(t6) (t8),label=above:$W$,style2,xscale=0.75,yscale=2.5] {};

    % the edges
    %\draw (f1) -- (s6);
    %\draw (s6) -- (f2);
    %\draw (f2) -- (s7);
    %\draw (s7) -- (f3);
    %\draw (s8) -- (f3);
    %\draw (f3) -- (s9);
    %\draw (s9) -- (f5);
    %\draw (f5) -- (s6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

one more possible solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 21mm,
      start chain = going below,
         V/.style = {circle, draw, 
                     fill=#1, 
                     inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm,
                     node contents={}},
 every fit/.style = {ellipse, draw=#1, inner ysep=-1mm, 
                     inner xsep=5mm},
                    ]
% vertices 
\foreach \i in {4,...,0} 
{
\ifnum\i=4
    \node (n1\i) [V=myblue,on chain,
                  label={[text=myblue]left:$u_{\i}$}];
\else
    \node (n1\i) [V=myblue,on chain,
                  label={[text=myblue]left:$u_{\i}$}];
    \node (n2\i) [V=mygreen, above right=3.5mm and 22mm of n1\i,
                  label={[text=mygreen]right:$v_{\i}$}];
\fi
}
% set U
\node [myblue,fit=(n14) (n10),label=above:$U$] {};
% set V
\node [mygreen,fit=(n23) (n20),label=above:$V$] {};
% links
\draw[->, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]
        (n14) edge (n23)
        (n13) edge (n23)   (n13) edge (n22)
        (n12) edge (n21)   (n12) edge (n20)
        (n11) edge (n22)
        (n10) edge (n23)   (n10) edge (n20);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]