# Problems with the `graphs` library

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

According to the documentation for version 3.0.0 of PGF/TikZ (Section **19 Specifying Graphs**, page 258), the powerful `graphs` library:

> [...] offers a powerful path command for specifying how the nodes in a
>   graph are connected by edges and arcs: The graph path command, which
>   becomes available when you load the `graphs` library.

A few lines below there are some examples of the use of the path; amongst those examples one finds:

```
\tikz
  \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, n=5] {
    subgraph I_n [name=inner] --[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=outer]
};
```

and

```
\tikz
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};
```

which should produce the following images (taking directly from the documentation):

[image]

However, when I try the exact same code in a "real" document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}

 \tikz
  \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, n=5] {
    subgraph I_n [name=inner] --[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=outer]
};
\tikz
  \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
    subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
    subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};


\end{document}
```

This is all I get (image zoomed at 400%):

[image]

Even more disppointing is the following example on page 276:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph [simple] {
subgraph K_n [n=8, clockwise];
% Get rid of the following edges:
1 -!- 2;
3 -!- 4;
6 -!- 8;
% And make one edge red:
1 --[red] 3;
};

\end{document}
```

The documentation shows this as the result:

[image]

but I only get an error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.15 }
    ;
?
```

Am I missing something? Is some other library required in order to get the expected graphs?

Comment: Did some digging in the code for the documentation to find this: your MWEs work if the `graphs` _and_ `graphs.standard` libraries are loaded (in that order). I don't see why this requirement would be intentional... maybe a bug?

Comment: IMHO, the bug is with the `subgraph` keyword. It is not documented (alone)... and it offers no protection against errors: you may use any word after it without error (and without effect).

Comment: @PaulGessler That's correct, would you like to turn this comment into an answer?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, I could, but I'm not entirely sure _why_ both are required. The documentation only uses lists `graphs` as being needed, so I wasn't sure if this was expected/intended or not.

Comment: @PaulGessler `graphs.standard` is required to use `subgraph K_n` or `subgraph I_n`. The documentation only lists `graphs` because `subgraph ...` is used only to built an arbitrary graph in these examples.

Comment: Hmm.. the code of those first two examples look *exactly* the same.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro a copy-paste problem when I asked the question. I've corrected the code now. Thanks for noticing it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on looking through the [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) documentation's LaTeX source and also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15146/21344), I believe that the documentation should list that *both* the `graphs` and `graphs.standard` libraries are included to produce these graphics.

All your examples work if I use `\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}` instead of only `\usetikzlibrary{graphs}`. Here is one sample:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard} % both are required, in this order

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [simple] {
  subgraph K_n [n=8, clockwise];
  % Get rid of the following edges:
  1 -!- 2;
  3 -!- 4;
  6 -!- 8;
  % And make one edge red:
  1 --[red] 3;
};
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]