# How to create a probability space diagram?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I would like to create graphs similar to the one shown below using LaTeX. Is it possible to create such a graph? If so, which tools / libraries / techniques can I use to be able to do it?

[image: Probability Space]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Of course with lot of effort. For drawing of similar figures exist more LaTeX packages as `tikz`, `pstricks` etc.

Comment: Welcome to Tex SE! Is the graph in the picture the one you need to create, or is it something similar to it? And have you tried anything, perhaps using code found on this site?

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks! The actual contents of the sets does not matter (2 elements would suffice). What is important is that there are 2 sets, lines connecting, and a scale from 0 to 1. I haven't yet tried to code it because I don't know where to begin. I know it will take time and effort, which is why I don't want to tread down the wrong path from the get go. Any help on how to start would be great. [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/bipartite-graphs) is useful, but there's no scale from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final version

Here's the full image in a A4 page. You only need to fill the missing lines connecting the two groups, `s#` and `f#`. Remember that the counting start from the bottom, so `f1/s1` is the lowest node.

Note that the "thick" arrows/visible overlapping is only a PDF viewer issue.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit, shapes,chains, arrows.meta}

\newcommand\myarrow[2]{
    \path (#1) coordinate (a1) --++ (6,0) coordinate (a2);
    \coordinate (int) at (intersection of a1--a2 and #2--b#2);
    \draw[rounded corners,very thin,->] (#1) -- (int) -- (#2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[start chain=going above, node distance=2mm, shift={(-5,2)}]
    \foreach \i [count=\x] in {%
        {(TT)},
        {(TH)},
        {(HT)},
        {(HH)},
        }{%
        \node[on chain] (s\x) {\i};
    }
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[start chain=going above, node distance=2mm, shift={(0,1)}]
    \foreach \i [count=\x] in {%
        {\textbar(HT), (TH)\textbar},
        {\textbar(HH), (TT)\textbar},
        {\textbar(TH), (HT), (TT)\textbar},
        {\textbar(HT), (HH), (TH)\textbar},
        {\textbar(TT)\textbar},
        {\textbar(HH)\textbar},
        {$\varnothing$},
        {S}%
        }{%
        \node[on chain] (f\x) {\i};
    }
\end{scope}

\node [ellipse,draw,fit=(f1) (f8),label=above:$\mathscr{F}$] {};
\node [ellipse,draw,fit=(s1) (s4),label=above:S] {};

    \begin{scope}[x=5cm, shift={(1,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$P(\cdot)$};
        \foreach \x [count=\y] in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1}{
            \draw (\x,.2) coordinate (t\y) -- (\x,0) node[below] {\x};
            \path (t\y) --++ (95:5) coordinate (bt\y);
        }
    \end{scope}

\myarrow{f8}{t5}
\myarrow{f7}{t1}
\myarrow{f6}{t2}
\myarrow{f5}{t2}
\myarrow{f4}{t4}
\myarrow{f3}{t4}
\myarrow{f2}{t3}
\myarrow{f1}{t3}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{The relationship between the sample space, $\sigma$-field and probability set function.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Edit — overlapping arrows

Here's an example with the arrows like your scheme above. It uses a small "hack" to achieve the overlapping arrows effect, but it doesn't require you to load extra packages/libraries.

If you have any questions about the code, feel free to comment.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains, arrows.meta}

\newcommand\myarrow[2]{
    \path (#1) coordinate (a1) --++ (6,0) coordinate (a2);
    \coordinate (int) at (intersection of a1--a2 and #2--b#2);
    \draw[rounded corners,-{Latex}] (#1) -- (int) -- (#2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[start chain=going above, node distance=2mm, shift={(0,1)}]
        \foreach \i [count=\x] in {%
            {some node},
            {some other node},
            {short},
            {yet node},
            {what node},
            {that node},%
            }{
            \node[on chain] (\x) {\i};
        }
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[x=5cm, shift={(1,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
        \foreach \x [count=\y] in {0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}{
            \draw (\x,.2) coordinate (s\y) -- (\x,0) node[below] {\x};
            \path (s\y) --++ (98:5) coordinate (bs\y);
        }
    \end{scope}

\myarrow{1}{s3}
\myarrow{3}{s2}
\myarrow{5}{s3}
\myarrow{2}{s6}
\myarrow{6}{s1}
\myarrow{4}{s6}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

## Original answer

I'm not on my computer, so I can't post any code for now. But in the meantime, I can tell you what you can start looking at to create a graph like that.

1. The columns on the right can be done in various ways. I think the best way is using the TikZ `chains` library. Indeed, in this case chains have greater flexibility. For example, if you need to add nodes later on.
2. The scale on the right can be easily done with a line and a `\foreach` statement, which I'm sure you are familiar with in some way, to create the ticks and the labels. The syntax might differ, but it's the same command.
3. In both the first points, you can assign node references, that you can use to create arrows or connecting lines. As easy as `\draw (a) -- (b);`.

The graph is not hard per se, but it will require some typing. If you encounter problems, I'll give you some code snippets to show you how to approach a certain task.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will make a stab at it given the suggestions you've made - possibly returning to post my attempt. Tikz chains very useful. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh See edit for some code example

Comment: I used your answer to hack together my own version. It mightn't be pretty, but I think I got the gist of it. Thanks very much for your help! I appreciate it a lot. If you can improve my answer, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh I'm on it!

Comment: @GraemeWalsh See edited answer.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh No problem, you could also increase the distance in the first group of nodes to make the connecting lines more "sparse".

Answer (score 0):

Following the help provided by @Alenanno, I eventually ended up with the output and code shown below. I had to simplify the code provided by @Alenanno such that I could understand it. Of course, I expect that the graph could be created in a much neater and efficient way. I'm an absolute novice, so this is the best I can do.

### Output

[image: Probability space graph]

### CODE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc,arrows.meta}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Sample Space
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=7mm,inner sep=-2pt]
    \foreach \i [count=\x] in {%
        {(HH)},
        {(HT)},
        {(TH)},
        {(TT)},%
        }{
        \node[on chain] (s\x) {\i}; 
    }
\end{scope}
\node [ellipse,draw,fit=(s1) (s4),label=above:$\mathrm{S}$] {};

% Event Space
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm,yshift=1cm,start chain=going below,node distance=7mm,inner sep=-2pt]
    \foreach \i [count=\y] in {%
        {S},
        {$\varnothing$},
        {\{(HH)\}},
        {\{(TT)\}},
        {\{(HT),(HH),(TH)\}},
        {\{(TH),(HT),(TT)\}},
        {\{(HH),(TT)\}},
        {\{(HT),(TH)\}}%
        }{
        \node[on chain] (f\y) {\i}; 
    }
\end{scope}
\node [ellipse,draw,fit=(f1) (f8),label=above:$\mathscr{F}$] {};

% Elements of sample space mapped to the event space
\draw[-,very thin] (s1) --  (f1.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s1) -- (f3.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s1) -- (f5.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s1) -- (f7.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s2) -- (f1.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s2) -- (f5.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s2) -- (f6.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s2) -- (f8.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s3) -- (f1.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s3) -- (f5.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s3) -- (f6.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s3) -- (f8.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s4) -- (f1.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s4) -- (f4.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s4) -- (f6.west);
\draw[-,very thin] (s4) -- (f7.west);

% Probability Function
\begin{scope}[x=7cm, shift={(1,-7)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$P(\cdot)$};
        \foreach \x [count=\y] in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1}{
            \draw (\x,.2) coordinate (r\y) -- (\x,0) node[below] {\x};
            \path (r\y) --++ (98:5) coordinate (br\y);
        }
\end{scope}

% Elements of event space mapped to real number line
\draw[->,very thin] (f1.east) -- (12,-0.5) -- (r5);
\draw[->,very thin] (f2.east) -- (6,-0.5) -- (r1);
\draw[->,very thin] (f3.east) -- (8,-1.5) -- (r2);
\draw[->,very thin] (f4.east) -- (7.2,-1.6) -- (r2);
\draw[->,very thin] (f5.east) -- (11,-3) -- (r4);
\draw[->,very thin] (f6.east) -- (10.5,-3.2) -- (r4);
\draw[->,very thin] (f7.east) -- (9.5,-5) -- (r3);
\draw[->,very thin] (f8.east) -- (9,-5.2) -- (r3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The relationship between the sample space, $\sigma$-field and probability set function.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```