# Drawing graphs in latex with text-only vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I want to extend the implementations of the examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/bipartite-graphs) to represent  graphs with vertices simply represented as text as shown in the figure 
[image: below].

I wasn't able to find similar templates/examples in the tikz manual. Could someone point me to a MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify [Gonzalo's code (from the accepted answer to the question you refer to)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15094/586) to only have text, for example

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

% the vertices of U
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach [count=\i] \txt/\xcoord/\ycoord in {ABC/6/8,CDE/5/1,FGH/-4/7,IJK/6/9,LMN/0/-3}
  \node[on chain] (f\i) {\txt};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of V
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-0.5cm,start chain=going below,node distance=7mm]
\foreach [count=\i from 6] \txt/\xcoord/\ycoord in {OPQ/0/3,RST/1/4,UVW/-2/1,XYZ/5/9}
  \node[on chain] (s\i) {\txt};
\end{scope}


% the edges
\begin{scope}[auto]
\draw (f1) --node{1} (s6);
\draw (s6) --node[swap]{2} (f2);
\draw (f2) --node{3} (s7);
\draw (s7) --node{4} (f3);
\draw (s8) --node{5} (f3);
\draw (f3) --node[swap]{6} (s9);
\draw (s9) --node{7} (f5);
\draw (f5) --node{8} (s6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you point to Gonzalo's code?

Comment: @envy_intelligence You did that ... It's the accepted answer to the question you referred to.